# Reinterpret cast safety for proxying a type

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I'm wondering whether it is safe to do the following:

The original type (defined outside of my code):

```
struct Original
{
    unsigned long        index;
    double               x;
    double               y;
};
```

My proxy type (which adds one or more auxiliary member variables):

```
struct Proxy
{
    unsigned long        index;
    double               x;
    double               y;
    unsigned long        aux_data;
};
```

Function signature for external function:

```
void external_func(Original* arr, int len);
```

Usage:

```
int len;
Proxy* arr = new Proxy[ len ];
external_func( reinterpret_cast<Original*>( arr ), len );
delete[] arr;
```

The Original struct is defined within a library I'm using (and cannot edit directly). This library also contains functions that access an Original* array. For my purposes, it would be helpful for each of these objects to store some auxiliary data (that would be accessed through parts of my code but not by the external library). Naturally, if Original were part of my code, I would just use inheritance/polymorphism here.

Alternately, would it be better to do this:

```
class Proxy : public Original
{
public:

  unsigned long        aux_data;
};
```

Do I need to worry about a virtual constructor here?
And would I use dynamic_cast instead of reinterpret_cast?

Comment: No it's not safe, it's undefined behavior. Use either composition or inheritance - whichever one makes the most sense.

Comment: Given the "Original" type shown above, would the inheritance approach shown above be ok?

Comment: After a second look, no that's not going to work without modifying the library. The reason is `external_func` is expecting an array of `Original` objects but you're passing it an array of `Proxy` objects. Since the proxy object is larger any access of the array (except possible the first element) will result in UB.

Comment: Indeed, *no* method to extend `Original` will work, as all of them add to the size of the object. The only way I see is to store the extra data elsewhere, for example in a `std::map<Original*, unsigned long>`. However that will require manual management of that map.

Comment: Thanks to you both. That's what I was afraid of. Ok, guess I'll have to go with a clunkier work-around.